# Can two products with the same name but different category produce unique URLs?

Tags: permalinks, urls, woocommerce-offtopic

In the permalinks settings I have `/courses/%product_cat%`. Using WooCommerce I created two different Courses that are named "English", but they have different categories that end up making my urls look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/demo/chla/courses/grade-11/physics/
https://www.example.com/demo/chla/courses/grade-12/physics-2/
```

The Grade 12 URL is not ideal with the "-2" attached onto "physics". Is there anything I can do to remove that?

Comment: "physics" must be unique because it is the `post_name` ('slug') and does not depend on any taxonomy.

Comment: so my only option is to rename the slug?

Comment: I am also stuck in this. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You get this behavior as following:

- Create a page as category name.
- A product page, make it child of your category.
- Use `[product_page id="0"]` to display a product.

You can now use the same product name in different categories.

Comment: this is helpful